# Django: Model Inheritance: FK & M2M

Tags: django, inheritance, django-models, data-modeling

I dam trying to do this: 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name

Using this style

This is saved as common/abstract.py

```
class OtherModel(models.Model):

   something = Charfield(max_length=100)

   class Meta:
            abstract = True

class Base(models.Model):
        fk_model = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

        class Meta:
            abstract = True
```

Then I import it into another file. Let's call this app/models.py

```
from common.abstract import Base

class ChildB(Base):
    pass
```

I have installed 'app' but not the 'common'. It will import nicely without the FK or M2M relationship, but when I try to add it, I get this error:

/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 808, in **init**
    assert not to.*meta.abstract, "%s cannot define a relation with abstract class %s" % (self.**class**.*_name__, to._meta.object_name)
AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class OtherModel

Please advise.... also let me know if you have any questions or don't understand something that I am explaining. The file that I working with is really complex, so I didn't want to post the whole thing since I knew that it is breaking on this one relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem.....

**This will work:**

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Base(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ForeignKey(CommonInfo, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildA(Base):
    pass
```

**This will give you the error: AssertionError: ForeignKey cannot define a relation with abstract class OtherModel**.This is because you can't have a FK relationship or M2M relationship on an abstract pointing to ANOTHER abstract class.

```
from django.db import models

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Base(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ForeignKey(CommonInfo, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ChildA(Base):
    pass
```

This is sad news for me. Sad news indeed. I hope my sad news benefits someone else.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a relation with an abstract model, but this is what you are trying to do (`ManyToManyField` to `OtherModel`). If you want to make this work you need to remove `abstract = True` from `OtherModel` and add `common` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`!

If you want to relate to different sublasses of `OtherModel` from the subclasses of `Base` you will need to define the relation on the subclass, not on the abstract model!

Comment: That's what I thought, but what I don't understand is the docs give me the impression that I can have the relation. Am I wrong in the way I did it or are the docs wrong?

Comment: I do not know to which topic in the documentation you are referring exactly, but I do no think there would be any sense in defining a relation to an abstract model...